# android how to make top float notification like wechat message notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

Hi like this photo for top message notification, I have tried to notify, I can get notification shown in a status bar, but never to show float notification message view at the top,
who can give me the same code to show?
thanks~[image]

Comment: this is what you need https://android.jlelse.eu/custom-layouts-for-your-push-notification-d8219d9962e

Answer (score 2):

Beginning from Android 5.0 Lollipop version, Android had introduced Heads-up Notification. Please check [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#Heads-up) for more information.

Example conditions that might trigger heads-up notifications include the following:

1. The user's activity is in fullscreen mode (the app uses fullScreenIntent).
2. The notification has high priority and uses ringtones or vibrations on devices running Android 7.1 (API level 25) and lower.
3. The notification channel has high importance on devices running Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher.

You can turn it off by asking the user to turn off `Allow peeking` in the App Notifications section. Please check [this link](https://www.greenbot.com/article/2990514/how-to-turn-off-heads-up-notifications-in-android-marshmallow.html) for more info.